# UStaticMeshComponent::SetStaticMesh() crash; how to create a static mesh from raw mesh data in UE5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am trying to create a static mesh from a raw mesh data (vertex + index buffer) at runtime.

First, I was able to successfully create a static sphere mesh (using `StaticLoadObject` to load "/Engine/BasicShapes/Sphere") and to assign the same material (as returned by `AMyActor::CreateMaterial` below).

Then, instead of the sphere mesh, I want to create my vertex and index data at runtime.

With information I found around, I wrote the following code:

```
UStaticMeshComponent* AMyActor::CreateMesh(AActor* ActorOwner, FLinearColor Color)
{
    FRawMesh RawMesh;
    RawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    RawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector(100.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    RawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector(100.f, 100.f, 0.f));
    RawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector(0.f, 100.f, 0.f));

    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(0);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(1);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(2);

    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(0);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(2);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(3);

    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(1);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(0);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(3);

    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(1);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(3);
    RawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(2);

    // Create a static mesh from the FRawMesh
    UStaticMesh* StaticMesh = NewObject<UStaticMesh>();
    StaticMesh->AddSourceModel();
    FStaticMeshSourceModel& SourceModel = StaticMesh->GetSourceModel(0);
    SourceModel.RawMeshBulkData->SaveRawMesh(RawMesh);

    StaticMesh->Build(false);

    UStaticMeshComponent* Mesh = NewObject<UStaticMeshComponent>(ActorOwner);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Calling Mesh->SetStaticMesh(%x)..."), (void*)StaticMesh);
    // crashes here:
    Mesh->SetStaticMesh(StaticMesh);
    Mesh->SetMaterial(0, CreateMaterial(Color));
    Mesh->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Pawn"));
    Mesh->SetHiddenInGame(false);
    Mesh->RegisterComponent();
    return Mesh;
}

UMaterialInstanceDynamic* AMyActor::CreateMaterial(FLinearColor Color)
{
    FStringAssetReference MaterialRef(TEXT("/Game/SimBlank/Materials/GlossyRedMaterial"));
    UMaterialInterface* LoadedMaterial = Cast<UMaterialInterface>(StaticLoadObject(UMaterialInterface::StaticClass(), nullptr, *MaterialRef.ToString()));
    UMaterialInstanceDynamic* NewMaterial = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(LoadedMaterial, this);
    NewMaterial->SetVectorParameterValue("BaseColor", Color);
    return NewMaterial;
}
```

which I call in the first tick of my plugin, with:

```
MeshActor = World->SpawnActor<AActor>();
MeshActor->SetRootComponent(CreateMesh(MeshActor, FLinearColor::Gray));
MeshActor->SetActorLocation(GetActorLocation() + FVector(100.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f));
```

but the above code crashes at `Mesh->SetStaticMesh(StaticMesh);`.

Before crashing it prints:

Assertion failed: (Index >= 0) & (Index < ArrayNum) [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers\Array.h] [Line: 752] Array index out of bounds: 0 from an array of size 0

To make a simpler test, I removed the part where I create the `FRawMesh` and also the call to `SourceModel.RawMeshBulkData->SaveRawMesh(RawMesh)`, however it crashes in the same way, with the same assertion failed message. Code:

```
UStaticMeshComponent* AMyActor::CreateMesh(AActor* ActorOwner, FLinearColor Color)
{
    UStaticMesh* StaticMesh = NewObject<UStaticMesh>();
    StaticMesh->AddSourceModel();
    FStaticMeshSourceModel& SourceModel = StaticMesh->GetSourceModel(0);
    //SourceModel.RawMeshBulkData->SaveRawMesh(RawMesh);

    StaticMesh->Build(false);

    UStaticMeshComponent* Mesh = NewObject<UStaticMeshComponent>(ActorOwner);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Calling Mesh->SetStaticMesh(%x)..."), (void*)StaticMesh);
    // crashes here:
    Mesh->SetStaticMesh(StaticMesh);
    Mesh->SetMaterial(0, CreateMaterial(Color));
    Mesh->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Pawn"));
    Mesh->SetHiddenInGame(false);
    Mesh->RegisterComponent();
    return Mesh;
}
```

What's the correct way to create a static mesh from raw mesh data?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `RawMesh` is missing additional information. I haven't tested your code but creating `RawMesh` and saving it to the `StaticMesh` works on my end by adding values in `WedgeColors`, `WedgeTangent`, `WedgeTexCoords`, `FaceMaterialIndices` and `FaceSmoothingMasks`.

As an example:

```
FRawMesh CreateQuadRawMesh()
{
    FVector3f EmptyVector = FVector3f(0, 0, 0);
    FColor WhiteVertex = FColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

    FRawMesh QuadRawMesh;
    QuadRawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    QuadRawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector3f(100.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    QuadRawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector3f(100.f, 100.f, 0.f));
    QuadRawMesh.VertexPositions.Emplace(FVector3f(0.f, 100.f, 0.f));

    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(0);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(1);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(2);

    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(0);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(2);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(3);

    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(1);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(0);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(3);

    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(1);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(3);
    QuadRawMesh.WedgeIndices.Emplace(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeColors.Add(WhiteVertex);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeColors.Add(WhiteVertex);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeColors.Add(WhiteVertex);

        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentX.Add(EmptyVector);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentX.Add(EmptyVector);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentX.Add(EmptyVector);

        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentY.Add(EmptyVector);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentY.Add(EmptyVector);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentY.Add(EmptyVector);

        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentZ.Add(EmptyVector);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentZ.Add(EmptyVector);
        QuadRawMesh.WedgeTangentZ.Add(EmptyVector);

        for (int UVIndex = 0; UVIndex < MAX_MESH_TEXTURE_COORDS; UVIndex++)
        {
            QuadRawMesh.WedgeTexCoords[UVIndex].Add(FVector2f(0.0f, 0.0f));
            QuadRawMesh.WedgeTexCoords[UVIndex].Add(FVector2f(0.0f, 0.0f));
            QuadRawMesh.WedgeTexCoords[UVIndex].Add(FVector2f(0.0f, 0.0f));
        }

        QuadRawMesh.FaceMaterialIndices.Add(0);
        QuadRawMesh.FaceSmoothingMasks.Add(0xFFFFFFFF); // Phong ?
    }

    return QuadRawMesh;
}
```